# How to display clock with product publish date in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a way to add a column titled "Product release time" to the products table(Woo Product Table). But WordPress only shows the date and I want the publication time (like 10:50) to be displayed after the date

I would very grateful for any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to Settings / General from your dashboard.

Choose a custom Date Format that also includes the time-formatting characters.

For example, if your original date format is `F j, Y` you can change it to `F j, Y g:i a` to see the time shown next to the date.